# Avoiding Groovy/Grails internals while debugging in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: debugging, grails, groovy, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ Idea 8.1.2 for Grails development. The dynamic nature of Groovy is giving me a hard time debugging my code: I keep ending up in the internals of Groovy/Grails, i.e. CachedMethod, ExpandoMetaClass or the like.

Is there a way for example to tell the Idea debugger to completely skip the Groovy/Grails internals while debugging and only make steps in my own code? I did notice that there is a configuration option named "Do not step into specific Groovy classes" in Debugger > Groovy but so far I've noticed no difference.

If not, what is your workaround or how do you cope with the situation? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

File->Settings->Debugger->Stepping

Do not step into the classes...

Comment: I added 'groovy.*' and 'org.codehaus.groovy.*' and by a quick test it seems to work just the way I wanted it to. Thank you so much!

Comment: My current exclusion patterns are:

groovy.*; 
org.codehaus.groovy.*;
org.springframerwork.*;
org.mortbay.* (for Jetty)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I suffer with this annoyance, too, and I don't have a good solution. My workaround once I'm lost in Groovy/Grails code is just to figure out where I should be back in my code, set a break point there, and hit Continue.